All declarations of 'root' must have identical modifiers
Im on angular version 13.4.0
Node version 22.11.0
Typescript version 4.6.4
On executing command
"ng build --aot --configuration production --source-map=false --output-hashing=none --base-href=/ux/"
I get the following errors:
How can I get this to build successfully? Thanks in advance!

Error: node_modules/@types/filesystem/index.d.ts:365:11 - error
TS2304: Cannot find name 'DOMError'. [INFO] [INFO] 365     (err:
DOMError): void; [INFO]               ~~~~~~~~ [INFO] [INFO] [INFO]
Error: node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:5303:14 - error
TS2687: All declarations of 'name' must have identical modifiers.
[INFO] [INFO] 5303     readonly name: string; [INFO]                  
~~~~ [INFO] [INFO] [INFO] Error:
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:5304:14 - error TS2687: All
declarations of 'root' must have identical modifiers. [INFO] [INFO]
5304     readonly root: FileSystemDirectoryEntry; [INFO]



dunno if this'll help, but https://github.com/georgipeltekov/ngx-file-drop/issues/252
